# Minimum no of bits to represent X

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

[image]
 It took me much time to reach the solution where I find the value of X as 2 but still not sure whether this is correct or not.
please help me with the solution

Comment: how did you get to your solution that $X=2$?

Comment: $X\neq2$, that is for sure. In fact, $X$ is odd.

Comment: Yes there I also asked the same question after editing but no one gave the answer that's why i posted it and ask it again

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y = (61^{610}+1,61^{671}-1)^{61}$. Then, the expression becomes $$X=(Y\cdot Y^{10}+1,Y^{10}-1)$$Note that $Y\cdot Y^{10}+1=Y\cdot(Y^{10}-1)+Y-1$. And, $Y$ clearly has no common factors with either of the terms. So, this gcd is equivalent to $$(Y-1,Y^{10}-1)$$But, this is clearly equal to $Y-1$ as $Y-1|Y^{10}-1$. So, $X=Y-1$.

So we have $$X=(61^{610}+1,61^{671}-1)^{61}+1$$

**EDIT**

With Robert Israel's work, $Y=2^{61}$, so $X=2^{61}+1$, which clearly takes $62$ bits to express. And, we also note that since $2$ has a cyclicity of $4$, $2^{61}$ has a last digit of $2$, so $X\mod10=3$.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that $(61^{610}+1, 61^{671}-1) = 2$, while
$(2^{671}+1, 2^{610}-1) =2305843009213693953 = 3 \cdot 768614336404564651$.

Note btw that the gcd of the polynomials $x^{671}+1$ and $x^{610}-1$ is
$x^{61} + 1$, and $2305843009213693953 = 2^{61}+1$.

Comment: How in the heck...

Comment: Almost instantaneous using Maple.....

Comment: Ahhhh. welp. There goes my algebra